# In Rx.NET, how to enrich values from a (async/observable) lookup

Tags: system.reactive

Lets say I have a stream of bids - and i want to enrich it with the bidders names:

```
[
  { bidder: 'user/7', bet: 20  },
  { bidder: 'user/8', bet: 21 }, 
  { bidder: 'user/7', bet: 25  }, 
  /*...., 2 seconds later */
  { bidder: 'user/8', bet: 25  },
  { bidder: 'user/9', bet: 30  },
  ...
```

Bidder names come from a webservice:

```
GET '/users?id=7&id=8' =>
[{ user: 'user/7', name: 'Hugo Boss'}, { user: 'user/8', name: "Karl Lagerfeld"}
```

Which i wrap into a reactive read-through-cache:

```
IObservable<User> Users(IObservable<string> userIds);
```

## Compose

Now I want to compose that into following output:

```
[
  { bidder: 'user/7', bet: 20, name: 'Hugo Boss'  },
  { bidder: 'user/8', bet: 21, name: 'Karl Lagerfeld' }, 
  { bidder: 'user/7', bet: 25, name: 'Hugo Boss'  }, 
  /*...., 2 seconds later */
  { bidder: 'user/8', bet: 25, name: 'Karl Lagerfeld'  },
  { bidder: 'user/9', bet: 30, name: 'Somebody else'  },
  ...
```

### Step 1

I guess I need to project the stream of bids to a stream of user ids. Simple `Select`. Then inside the read-throug-cache I split it up in chunks with `Buffer(TimeSpan, int)`.

Now I have a stream of bids and one of users.

### Step 2

But now, how to combine the two?

Hint: For the BIDs it would make sense to keep the order - but in my real code I don't care about the order. So I'd like to have a solution that does not rely on that the user cache returns users in the right order. Then a `Zip` could do the job.

I rather want to release all bids into my result stream as soon as I have the user information available.

### Solution?

I'm pretty sure I need to maintain some temporary state somehow (window/buffer/...). But I don't know where and how. 
Maybe this should be implemented as a custom operator; or maybe there is one out there already?

Any ideas?

**Edit:** It seems like it isn't possible to actually compose this on top of streams. Instead I need to get a promise (either Task or IObservable) for the userid->user function and leave it up to the promise to bulk load and/or cache users, if appropriate.

Comment: Why does the `Users` method take an `IObservable<string>`? Why not an enumerable?

Comment: Because a enumerable isn't reactive - it would block the thread waiting for the next user id (which might come tomorrow, in a second, or even never.

Comment: For me, IObservable in IObservable out feels odd. IMO, it feels more natural to have IObserver/IObservable pairs. In this case, I could imagine maybe a method taking a single value, and the cache being abstracted away. Inside your Users method, OnNexts the request. Caches are effectively an optimisation, they should be optional.

Comment: What I'm trying to describe is similar to the answer @bradgonesurfing has given.

Comment: You have to simplify what you are asking. The simple thing is that you ask the cache for a ``single`` user and the cache provides you with a promise, ``Task<User>``, that it will provide that user sometime in the future. Internally the cache can buffer cache misses and batch requests to the server. The user then pairs the ``Task<User>`` with the Bid object and waits for the task to complete or error out. When the task completes you now have a pair of User and Bid. This pattern can be modelled with RX or TPL but the signiture, ``IObservable<User> Users(IObservable<string> userIds);`` won't work

Comment: I think I'm getting that i have to prep the join with a promise that then is fulfilled later, hence not really composing streams... I had a hope that I could compose what I want on top of two streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work. Represent the cache as an ISubject and you have an async cache. Internally in the cache you could buffer queries over a time window and batch request them to the server.

Some dummy classes

```
public struct User
{
    public string id;
}

public struct Bid
{
    public string userId;
    public int bid;
}
```

The cache object itself

```
/// <summary>
/// Represent the cache by a subject that get's notified of
/// user requests and produces users. Internally this can
/// be buffered and chunked to the server. 
/// </summary>
public static ISubject<string, User> UsersCacheSubject;
```

Method for dispatching and async queries to the DB

```
public static Task<User> UsersCache(string id)
{
    var r = UsersCacheSubject
        .Where(user=>user.id==id)
        .Replay(1)
        .Take(1);


    UsersCacheSubject.OnNext(id);

    return r.FirstAsync().ToTask();
}
```

try it out

```
 public void TryItOut()
{
    IObservable<Bid> bidderObservable = Observable.Repeat(new Bid());
     var foo = from bidder in bidderObservable
              from user in UsersCache(bidder.userId)
              where bidder.userId == user.id
              select new {bidder, user};
 }
```

Comment: IMO `UsersCache(string id)` reveals an implementation detail that shouldnt be exposed (subject name should stay the same). The client shouldn't need to care that its fetched, calculated or cached. You might see a `Get` on a `UserRepository`. Although, its a minor point.

Comment: There is no implementation detail exposed. Call UsersCache(string id) and you get a Task<T> that can be continued when complete. How that task is completed is an implementation detail but it's not exposed to the caller.

Comment: No, I mean, the fact that it is cached. The name itself. Caches are effectively an optimisation, they should be optional. I'd expect a concrete class to be named that way.

Comment: Ok. Just the name :) I can change that easily.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just as simple as doing the following?

```
var query =
    from b in bids
    from u in Users(Observable.Return(b.Bidder))
    select new
    {
        b.Bidder,
        b.Bet,
        u.Name
    };
```

Comment: Users should get one stream - and then be able to do optimizations (chunk loading, caching, ++)... With your code, Users would be called for each bet.. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually this would work but is more complex than it needs to be. Users should just take a single id and return a Task<User>. That task can complete immediately if the the item is in the cache or complete later if a server call is required. The nice thing is the implementation of Users can buffer the requests to the server and there is no requirement on the order of task completion. I've tried to elaborate a bit more in my answer above.

Comment: @LarsCorneliussen - I'm following the signature given by the OP. Nevertheless, it's probably not a good idea to hold an observable open for too long. It can lead to memory issues. Like any I/O resource they should be opened up and then closed when not needed.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing - I'm following the signature given by the OP. I'd be more inclined to have a simple `User GetUser(string userId)` signature and then wrap that in either `Observable.Start` or a `Task`. I'd prefer Rx because once you get into Rx it simply blows TPL away for 99% of all situations. :-)

Comment: Well the sig suppluied by the user is wrong for what they want to do because there is no way to associate the request for an id with the later event providing it. Sometimes it helps to point that out. As well in many cases TPL and RX are interchangable. If you are definately only returning a single value it sometime is clearer to use Task<T> rather than IOBservable<T> but it's not a big deal. LINQ eats both up nicely.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing - I agree. I do think it is good to pick one and stick with it. Changing from one monad to another is potentially dangerous. The signature supplied by the user is OK if the order of the observable elements remains the same. Observables are generally good in preserving the orders of items for any single operation.

Comment: It's wrong to imagine the the order of the input IObservable<String> and output IObservable<User> will be the same. It's easy to imagine ``['1', '2', '3'] -> [ 'user-3', 'user-1', 'user-2']`` user-3 is available from the cache but user-1 and user-2 take an unknown amount of time to be delivered. That's the whole point of async. Don't worry about the order.

Comment: In your case you are cheating wrapping your ``b.Bidder`` in an observable which you will immediately unwrap inside. It's not really behaving like an observable. Think what your implementation of Users would actually be.

Comment: I'm confused. Need to get back to it and then mark the answer according to what worked best. Or do you guys agree on the best answer? :-)